# Plot graphs by column name with a for loop

Tags: r, for-loop, graph, multiple-columns

When I want to create a single graph (with a red line provided by SMA function), this code works pretty well for me

```
sma <- SMA(df$col_name, n = 200)
plot(df$colname)
lines(sma, col = "red")
```

All I want is loop over all the columns in my df, so I don't need to type all the column names and repeat all the code.

This is what I tried so far:

```
for(i in colnames(df)) {
  sma <- SMA(df[,i], n = 200)
  plot(df[,i])
  lines(sma, col = "red")
}
```

But I got nothing.

Comment: Thank you @Edward, I forgot to paste it in my question.

Comment: So by nothing, you mean no plot or no smoothing average lines or nothing?

Comment: @Edward, I mean "no plot".

Comment: Not even the last one? Note that R base plots are replaced each time so you only see the last one.

Comment: @Edward, I tried another way and I got the last one. Thank you for letting me know that R base plots are always replaced. I'll try it another way, like ggplot2. Thank you.

Comment: ggplot won't help either. You need to decide where all there plots are to appear. In a file, or on the screen. If on screen, either use facetting (multi-panelling) or start a new window for each plot via `windows` or equivalent.